# Plot multiples values in the same Column graph

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I need to plot these graphs in the same plot, but i cant put it together, how can i make this?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import seaborn as sns

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    year=range(2010,2021), 
    qtd=[int(random.random() * 20) for x in range(2010,2021)], 
    monetary=[int(random.random() * int(random.random() * 10000)) for x in range(2010,2021)])
)
# fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot(x="year", y=['qtd',"monetary"], kind='bar',  figsize=(3, 3))
df.plot(x="year", y=['monetary','qtd'], kind='bar',  figsize=(3, 3))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- See [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for a description of all parameters.
- Plot grouped bars and set the y-axis to a log scale because the range of `'monetary'` is much larger than `'qtd'`. See the `logy=` parameter.
- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.2`, `matplotlib 3.6.2`**

  - These options do not explicitly require importing `matplotlib`, but `matplotlib` is imported by `pandas`, and is the default plotting backend.

```py
ax = df.plot(x="year", kind='bar', figsize=(6, 6), logy=True, rot=0)
```

[image]

- Plot in subplots and do not share the y-axis. Adjust the `layout=` parameter as needed. See the `sharey=` and `sharex=` parameters.

```py
ax = df.plot(x="year", kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(1, 2), figsize=(14, 6), sharey=False, rot=0, legend=False)
```

[image]

```py
ax = df.plot(x="year", kind='bar', subplots=True, layout=(2, 1), figsize=(6, 12), sharey=False, sharex=False, rot=0, legend=False)
```

[image]